# Создание персонажа под Mecanim, с чего начать?

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Всем привет. 
Возникла необходимость в проекте создать несколько персонажей которые в дальнейшем возможно придется анимировать. Хочется чтобы все это было сделано на базе `Mecanim`, дабы иметь богатый набор возможностей  для манипулирования ими. Стал искать с помощью чего можно сделать модели. Наткнулся на программу `MakeHuman` где даже человек далекий от 3D моделирования спокойно может создать заригинный скелет. Все хорошо, одно но, при одевании одежды на персонаж его модель упрощается, а хочется иметь возможность изменить на нем одежду на другую при необходимости. Нам требуется сделать неандертальца в набедренной повязке, думал возьму нацеплю юбку, дизайнер нарисует повязку подложим ее вместо текстуры юбки и обрежем по альфе шейдером, но за счет того что под юбкой ноги у модели отрезаны выходит такой способ не подходит.

Подскажите с помощью каких еще программ стоит делать персонажи под `Unity` чтобы они дружили с Mecanim. Буду признателен за наводки на туториалы.

Comment: blender https://www.blender.org/ .           3d max http://www.autodesk.ru/products/3ds-max/overview .        MakeHuman - делает тоже нормальные модели, а потом можно их перенести в 3D редактор и перемоделить как необходимо.

Comment: Главный вопрос был в чем делать модели чтобы одежда получалась отдельно от заригинного персонажа, чтобы я мог переодеть человека. А также интересует с помощью чего проще заанимировать готовые модели.

Comment: Модели и анимации можно делать там же(blender или 3d max или...). Еще можно скачать готовые анимации